# Связка MyVBAplication + MyDLL + MyDDEProcessC++

Tags: visual-basic, c++, dll

Стоит такая задача: В консольном приложении на С++ написан DDE сервер, который получает от стороннего приложения данные(в виде массива), требуется привязать DDE сервер к приложению написаному на VB

1) Мои размышления были такие - скомпилировать код DDE сервера в DLL, которую затем подключу к VB, но DLL это набор функций, и если к примеру я буду запускать сервер который размещён в DLL, используя функцию StartMyDDEServer(...) то я не получу возврат из этой функции, по причине того, что в DDE сервере реализован цикл обработки сообщений, следовательно чтобы получить возврат из функции нужно запустит отдельный поток, и выйти из функции, опять НО! Как только я выйду из функции как мне кажется принудительно закроется поток в котором будет работать сам сервак! Что делать!?

2) Второе что пришло на ум, консольное приложение DDE запустить как невидимый процесс, и ещё написать DLL для связи этого процесса (сервера) с приложением на VB. Здесь вообще тёмный лес. Как реализовать невидимый процесс (желательно иконку в системном трее), и как связать функции DLL c этим процессом!?

Требуется мнение и совет спецов! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

по п.2

- иконка в трее реализуется достаточно просто. Реализуется это через ф-цию [Shell_NotifyIcon](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762159.aspx). В любом случае окну будут посылаться WM* сообщения, которые нужно обрабатывать.
- DDE в самой программе работает через обработку сообщений WM* :-) При этом Вы сами определяете какие вызовы Вы обрабатываете. Поэтому в DLL просто пишете вызовы SendMessage с нужными ключами WM_DDE_*. Что-то в духе [такого](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms648775.aspx). А уже из прикладной программы вызываете нужные ф-ции библиотеки все в ажуре :-)
- если необходимо убрать основное окно программы, то насколько я помню, ему можно сделать [SW_HIDE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633548.aspx), правда уберет ли окно из списка задач на панели задач - не уверен. Способы сокрытия окон еще описаны [тут](http://zalexf.narod.ru/texts-taskbar.htm)